# Query to select a list of employees not returning desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: Schema Diagram]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/0231b1a3943be76da288b9dce07828a7.png))</sub>

I'm trying to list all employees' ID who work in Europe.

I have a query I created but it is not giving me the desired result

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.employee_id,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name
FROM
    employees e,
    job_history j,
    departments d,
    locations l,
    countries c,
    regions r
WHERE
    e.employee_id = j.employee_id and
    j.department_id = d.department_id and
    d.location_id = l.location_id and
    l.country_id = c.country_id and
    c.region_id = r.region_id and
    r.region_name = "Europe"
```

For example returns:

```
176 Jonathon    Taylor
```

While he is definitely an employee who works in Europe he is not the only one and I cannot seem to get my query to retrieve the other ones.

Comment: Do the other employees definitely have records on job_history? If not they'll be excluded based on your implicit inner join.

Comment: Your query does exactly what's expected of it. I suggest you take on of those "other employees", and track whether they indeed deserve to be in the result set (start with their record in `employees`, check that their `employee_id` appears in `job_history`, check the `department_id`s they worked in, verify their `locations`s, etc.)

Comment: Actually, they don't have records on job_history.

Comment: 1. Use explicit join syntax. Always.